# Getting the src attribute of a child element (child to <a>) in an iFrame and return it to the parent using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Since it's an iframe generated dynamically out of php and it just contains a list of pictures I want to get the src attribute of the clicked item (an image wrapped in an anchor tag) and return that to the parent or save it to a variable that can later be accessed by the parent.

The thing is jQuery is in the parent window, not the iframe itself so I have to use pure javascript and find a way to send the variable back to the parent. I've tried:

```
function(){
                $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('.clickable').click(function(){
                    alert('hey');
                });
```

from the parent window but it just doesn't work, so what I have now is an inline `onclick` event in the anchor of the image:

```
onClick=\"alert('this does work')\"
```

how can I manage to get the child's src attribute and send it back to the parent?

**EDIT**

I've also tried several variations of this:

```
onclick=\"this.className += 'pickedOne';\"
```

but I haven't been able to get it to set correctly.

All the elements inside the iframe have the following structure:

```
<div style=\"width: 300px; height:300px; float: left; margin-right:10px; \"><a onclick=\"this.className += 'pickedOne';\" title='".$value."' href='#'><img class='clickable' src=\"" . $value . "\" border=\"0\"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it with jQuery is ok, I have a web application that works the same way. jQuery is loaded in the parent window, and the events get fired inside the iframe using the same method you used.

Probably you used the wrong ID or class as a selector.

Also, make sure you are waiting for the content of the iframe to be loaded before trying to attach any event listener.

```
$('#fancybox-frame').load(function() {

    $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('.clickable').click(function(){
        alert('hey');
    });

});
```

Comment: I have that function as well and it just doesn't trigger anything, I'm guessing it has to do with the fancybox plugin being used but I really can't find a workaround that works...

Comment: `$('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { alert('hello'); });` try at least if it fires the load event of the iframe first.

Comment: nothing happened :( that's the iframe's id although it is contained in #fancybox-content would that have anything to do?

Comment: Is fancybox using an iframe too for showing the content? I know many of those plugins actually uses iframe to display content... if that's the case, you will first have to explore the contents of that iframe... yuck :)

Comment: well the iframe is created by the fancybox plugin itself. I just may have to do that but I really wouldn't know if it's an iframe within an iframe

Comment: When the fancybox content is showed, explore the element with your browsers, like Firebug for FF or Dragonfly for Opera. Then look at the DOM and see if there is some iframe holding the content.

Comment: @JoseFaeti let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2855/discussion-between-luis-armando-and-jose-faeti)